# How do you get to Tanned Land?

Tags: ios, order-and-chaos-online

I have just started playing Order and Chaos and reading some beginner guides online, it's a good idea to finish the quests in both starting areas to get a leg up when leveling up.

I started as a human and went to Silence to look for a way to get to the Tanned Land, where two of the other races start. However, the guides are not very helpful in saying how to get there.

Orcs and Undead can go to the Human and Elf starting area by just walking from Silence. How do Humans and Elves go to the other starting area?

Answer (score 1):

Teleport to Roar Military School by tapping it's name or icon.(only using teleport and no wings). when you will use teleport tap on choose tanned land and press roar military school icon. how i remember you need to be level 15 or more.

Comment: Tapping its name where? Please elaborate.

Comment: when you will use teleport tap on choose tanned land and press roar military school icon. how i remember you need to be level 15 or more.